# Number Of Paths To Take When Calculating Multivariable Limits

Tags: limits

How many paths do you need to take for a multi-variable limit before you can say that the limit exists with any amount of confidence. For example, I have the problem 
$$
\underset{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}{lim} \frac{x^2y \sin\left(\frac{1}{x+y}\right)}{x^2+y^2}
$$

I have evaluated this by taking $x=0$ and letting $y$ vary, taking $y=0$ and letting $x$ vary, by taking $x=y$, $y=x^2$, and $y=\alpha x$, which all come out to $0$. But I'm not sure if I'm missing some path which would not come out to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by $AM-GM$ we get
$$x^2+y^2\geq 2|x||y|$$ thus we get
$$\left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le \frac{x^2|y|}{2|xy|}=\frac{|x|}{2}$$ and this tends to Zero if $x$ tends to zero

Comment: What this concept is known as, for evaluating limits by taking their modulus and applying to them inequalities, where I can read on this (any specific link would help)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|f(x,y)| \le |x^2y|/(x^2+y^2) \le |y|[x^2/(x^2+y^2)].$